# Send Response in Loopback on remote method with afterRemote hook

Tags: node.js, email, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to process a request that needs a mail to be sent. In order to respond to the request without waiting for the mail to be sent i am sending the mail on an afterRemote hook. The method seems to run correctly and the mail is sent, but for some reason the cb function is not executed and as a result on the client the request remains unanswered. The problem is on the code that follows, as you can see i have `console.log("Here");cb(null,{});` there and the first command gets executed, but not the second as it seems.

```
  user.joinEntity = function(data, cb) {
    var loopbackCtx = user.app.loopback.getCurrentContext();
    var userId=loopbackCtx.accessToken.userId;
    if(false){
        cb( new Error("Cant join that Entity."),{});
    }else{
        user.find({where:{id:userId}},function(err,applicant_instance){
            if (err) cb(err,{});
            if(applicant_instance.length>0)
            user.find({where:{id:data.ownerId}},function(err,founder_instance){
                if (err) cb(err,{});
                if(founder_instance.length>0)
                user.app.models.EntityApplication.create({email:applicant_instance[0].email,userId:userId,EntityFounder:founder_instance[0].id,Entity:data.id,Status:"pending"},function(err,Entity_Application_Instance){
                    if (err) cb(err,{});
                    loopbackCtx.join_entity={applicant:applicant_instance[0].email,entity:data.name,to:founder_instance[0].email};
                    console.log("Here");
                    cb(null,{});
                });
            });
        })
    }
  }
  user.afterRemote('joinEntity',function(){
      var loopbackCtx = user.app.loopback.getCurrentContext();
      user.app.models.Email.send({
        to: loopbackCtx.join_entity.to,
        from: 'mailer@domain.org',
        subject: 'Application to enter your Entity',
        // text: '<strong>HTML</strong> tags are not converted'
        html: 'User <strong>'+loopbackCtx.join_entity.applicant+'</strong> wants to enter Entity by the name of <strong>'+loopbackCtx.join_entity.entity+'</strong>'
      }, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('> email sent successfully');       
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hey @Evan,  are you getting an error message?  And the client just hangs?  One thing you might try is `console.log(cb)` to be sure your callback exists.  I don't see any reason it wouldn't, but it's a decent sanity check.  - Brennan

Comment: @BrennanPayne Hey, there is no error and the callback seems to be defined. This is very weird >:(

Comment: Interesting.  It's possible that the callback is actually being called?  Do you expect the `user.afterRemote('joinEntity' ...` to be called after your this callback.  Have you debugged to be sure the issue isn't in that method?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'll want to be sure to execute the `next()` callback on a remote hook to tell LB (or rather Express) that you want this particular piece of middleware to allow processing to continue. If you don't call `next()` then you're basically telling Express that this is the end of middleware processing. Make sure you accept all three arguments to the remote hook, then execute `next()` when the method action is complete:

```
user.afterRemote('joinEntity',function(ctx, instance, next){
  // *** notice arguments above!

  var loopbackCtx = user.app.loopback.getCurrentContext();
  user.app.models.Email.send({
    to: loopbackCtx.join_entity.to,
    from: 'mailer@domain.org',
    subject: 'Application to enter your Entity',
    // text: '<strong>HTML</strong> tags are not converted'
    html: 'User <strong>'+loopbackCtx.join_entity.applicant+'</strong> wants to enter Entity by the name of <strong>'+loopbackCtx.join_entity.entity+'</strong>'

  }, function(err) {
    // *** notice the correct way to indicate an error!
    if (err) { next(err); }

    console.log('> email sent successfully');

    // *** Now tell Express to keep processing middleware
    next();
  });
});
```